# Suppose the only $R$-stable subspaces of $V$ is $0$ and $V$ itself. Prove $V$ is one dimensional.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R be a commutative ring of endomorphisms of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $C$ with a hermitian inner product.  $R$ is closed under taking adjoints with respect to the inner product. Suppose the only $R$-stable subspaces of $V$ is $0$ and $V$ itself. Prove $V$ is one dimensional.

$R$ is a set of endomorphisms, does $R$-stable mean stable with respect to each elements in $R$? how to prove?

Answer (score 3):

If $R=0$, then every subspace of $V$ is stable. If $dimV\geq 2$, take $e_1,e_2\in V$ independent, $Vect(e_1)\neq V$ stable contradiction.

Suppose $R\neq 0$ and $r\in R$ not zero; $r$ has an eigenvalue $c\neq 0$. Let $V_c$ the eigenspace associated to $c$. For every $r'\in R, x\in V_c, r(r'(x))=r'(r(x))=r'(cx)=cx$ implies that $V_c$ is stable by $R$. $V'$ the orthogonal of $V_c$ is stable since $R$  is closed under adjoint. This implies that $V_c=V$ Since $V_c\neq \{0\}$ and only $V$ and $\{0\}$ are stable. We deduce that every element of $R$ is diagonal. If $dimV>1$, there exists $u\in V, Vect(u)\neq V$, $Vect(u)$ is stable by $R$, contradiction.

Comment: It seems we can drop the requirement for the adjoints: $V_c$ is nonzero (contains $x$) and $R$-stable, so by hypothesis, $V_c=V$.